# If I code in the functional paradigm on CoffeeScript, will I get JavaScript compiled code to be containing functional programs too?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, coffeescript

CoffeeScript compiles into JavaScript, and it states that it is a functional language. So if I write code in the functional manner on CoffeeScript, will I get JavaScript compiled code to be containing functional programs too?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can write code in the functional paradigm (loosely, "style") directly in JavaScript. If you write code in the functional paradigm in CoffeeScript (or TypeScript, or Dart, or...) and then transpile it to JavaScript, that doesn't change the paradigm it uses, just the language.